# How to display multiple images in a single picturebox in c# windows form?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I'm a beginner in developing c# windows form in visual studio and i'm a little bit confused with its programming constructs compared to VB.NET that i'm used to program. I want to know how to display multiple images in a single picturebox because in vb.net you will just import the image then load it from the resources not like in c# that I think the coding is different. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to display multiple images in a single PictrueBox. PictureBox-Controls are not designed something like that. May you should a UserControl in which you can add some PictureBoxes or something like that.

Comment: Thank you sir but the program that want to create which is a Jack N' Poy wherein there are 3 buttons: Scissors, Paper and rock and if the user press any of the 3 then the picture of it will be displayed in the picture box in other words in other words 1 picture box with 3 pictures.

Comment: Do you want to get a PictrueBox containing three images of a Scissors-, a Paper- and a Rock-Icon? To enable the user to click on one image for an action of his choice?

Comment: Sir what do you mean to enable the user to click on one image for an action of his choice? I want the user to choose from the 3 buttons then the button that he will select will be displayed in the picturebox. Not the image that will be clicked.

Comment: Sounds a lot like you should use 3 buttons with no text and the images as their Image (or BackgroundImage) ! Of course one __can__ display as many Images as one wants onto just about __any__ control (using the right DrawImage overload), but all in all three Buttons seem like the natural choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create an ImageList with all the Images you want to show in your PictureBox, add the three Buttons to your Form and change the Picture on Click.

[image: Image of my example Form]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private ImageList imagelst;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        imagelst = new ImageList();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //pictures from your Harddrive
        Image i = new Bitmap("rock.jpg");
        imagelst.Images.Add("rock", i);

        i = new Bitmap("scissors.jpg");
        imagelst.Images.Add("scissors", i);

        i = new Bitmap("paper.jpg");
        imagelst.Images.Add("paper", i);
    }

    private void btnRock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = imagelst.Images["rock"];
    }

    private void btnScissors_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = imagelst.Images["scissors"];
    }

    private void btnPaper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = imagelst.Images["paper"];
    }
}
```

I hope I got what you want to do. If not excuse my bad english and slow-wittedness, please.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention: You can also access Images you added as Project-Resource [Right-Click on Project -> Resources -> (on top) choose Pictures -> (on the right of that) choose exsiting resource -> choose image file]. If you add a file named rock.jpg you can set the picturebox like this `pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.rock;`

Comment: an error occurred when I ran it saying invalid parameter on the instantiation part in the form_load

Comment: So no need for me to instantiate ImageList?

Comment: Yes. No ImageList needed if you use `Properties.Resources.Imagename`. Sorry, I forgot this nice feature of .net VisualStudio-Projects.

Comment: Thank you very much @the_mario! It worked! I have used the properties and imported the images to the resource, i just wanted to ask what's the use of the instantiation of imagelist and when will I use it. Please reply.TY

Comment: An ImageList is a nice way to have a managed set of Images in Memory. You can load them once with the Filename, a Stream or get it on an other way e.g. from a Graphics-Object into an instance of ImageList. Once you added your images, you access them on a nice way like keys or so. In the above code is the declaration in _line 4_: `private ImageList imagelst;`. To use `imagelst`, I instantiated it in _line 9_: `imagelst = new ImageList();`. If this wouldn't be, it would cause an NullPointerReferenceException in _line 16_: `imagelst.Images.Add("rock", i);`